# Where exactly do I add my BMP files in my OpenGL C++ project? Using Xcode for the Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, textures, bmp

I have my code working perfectly on Visual Studio C++ with OpenGL. The code is able to call the images folder. And when I run the program the images show up on my application.

Now I am trying to run my OpenGL C++ program on my Mac. Everything compiles and runs. However, the images that I use are not showing up.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of how my project directory looks. I have the images inside the texture folder.

Is there specific place where I need to put my texture folder so they will be able to be loaded? Like I said it works fine on the windows visual C++.

Comment: It completely depends on how the images are being searched for and loaded. We can't really help without seeing some code.

Comment: The code itself shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: http://i.tinyuploads.com/6OdQll.png there's a screenshot, how I'm calling the images

Comment: @SeaCode; The code always matters. And if you have code to show us, just put it into the StackOverflow question. slavik262 already gave you the answer to your problem. Indeed your code mattered, namely that you hardcoded the paths into it, using the Windows way, which no other OS than Windows uses.

Comment: the reason i dont want to put my code is that it is a school project. and i dont want my prof to think i got it off online. thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Given the screenshot you posed in the comments, it could be because you're using backslashes for the path separators. UNIX-based systems (Mac, Linux, BSD, etc.) use forward slashes to separate directories - Windows is fairly unique in using the backslash. Conveniently, Windows functions will accept paths with forward slashes anyways.

Comment: Sorry for the slow responses. You'd need to change \\ to /. \\ turns into a single backslash in the actual string. This is because a backslash is used to denote a special character; a newline is \n for example. So \\ is used to denote a single backslash.